# File History Cleanup errors with 800405ff

Tags: windows-8.1, disk-cleanup, file-history

I'm trying to clean up my File History items on Window 8.1, but when I click on the "Clean up versions" I get the following error:

> **Could not clean up File History data**
>
> Failed to perform File History cleanup (error 800405ff)

This happens every time I click the button.  The Event Log shows nothing, so I'm not sure where to go from here.  What can I do to reset my File History, or at least clean up some of the old versions?

Comment: Try opening Windows Explorer as Administrator.

Comment: Tried that, it still gave me the same error

Answer (score 0):

Things to try:

1. Try to clean up File History when booting in Safe mode
2. [Check your File History drive](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows-8/what-something-goes-wrong-file-history) for errors via chkdsk and Repair in Action Center
3. [Select a different File History drive](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows-8/what-something-goes-wrong-file-history)
4. Delete (but save) files at :
   `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\FileHistory\Configuration`.
   In case of the lack of access permissions, do this from a Linux Live CD.
5. Try [these methods](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/25820-file-history-cleanup-delete-older-versions-windows-8-a.html) :

   - Use File History Cleanup from Control Panel
   - Use File History Cleanup from Command Prompt